# Fail Add Active Navigation Class Based on URL

Tags: javascript

I have a basic menu structure on my blog using code below. I've tried every snipped and also doing some of similar topics here but nothing works.
All I want to do is to add active class to my navigation menu based on url. So the visitors or user on the website knows on which page or part of the site he is on.
So, can someone please explain simply where and how to add in javascript to do this ?

Menu structure

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="backer" style="position: relative;">
<div class="header-inner-wrap">
<div class="header section" id="header">
<div class="widget Header" data-version="1" id="Header1">
<h1><div id="header-inner">
<a href=""></a></div></h1>
</div></div>
</div>
<nav class="main-nav" itemscope="itemscope" role="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">Tutorial</a></li>
<li><a href="">Tips</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("menu li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

CSS:

```
.menu li .active{border-bottom:3px blue solid;}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that all anchors in your page will not contain slash `/`? That is what your jquery code presumes by doing `var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check that your selector for menu class is matching something:

```
$("menu li a").each(function(){
```

ahould be

```
$(".menu li a").each(function(){
```

**EDIT:** Based on new information, the following change should fix your problem.

Change from

```
var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

to

```
var pgurl = window.location.href;
```

And the `or` part of your condition is unnecessary. So change from this

```
$("menu li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
      $(this).addClass("active");
 })
```

to this

```
$(".menu li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl){
          $(this).addClass("active");
      }
 });
```

Apart from this solving your immediate problem, you should endeavour to learn javascript properly instead of copying and using snippets, so you can easily analyze your code and detect the cause of your issue.

Comment: `$(".menu li a").each(function(){` it still not working.

Comment: Is that the actual html you are using? if it is, you should note that all the hrefs are empty, so you won't see anything change.

Comment: sorry for the shortage of code I wrote, here is my complete hrefs `<li><a href="http://www.excelive.com/p/about-us.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.excelive.com/p/tutorial.html">Tutorial</a></li>`

Comment: Therein lies your problem. You need to remove the portion that checks for the tail of the url and just use the full url to compare. Updating my answer to reflect this...